# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' Error

Tags: laravel, database

Every time I try to save the filled records the server responses in 500 in my laravel project. The following is screencast for the error. It is always just happened only in my local development but not at other dev's local. I have tried the following but it still happens.

1. refresh and seed DB again
2. clear cache
   [image]

Comment: verify that your primary key is **auto_increment**

Comment: Add your table migrations